# 'If' loop' with and doesn't print message when inputs conditions are True

Tags: python, email, if-statement, logic

I'm trying to write a mini code that check if user/keys inputs are correct, code is the next:

```
if emailstatus == True and email in UserKeys == True and UserKeys [email] == key :

  print ('Checked,  you can log in ')    

else:

  print ('wrong email or password, you can not log in')
'''
```

When I enter a correct email and password I still can't login (which generates a triple True values

I FIXED THIS adding  '()' to if condition in **(** email in UserKeys **)** == True

but still I don't understand the logic behind this error

Pd: complete program code is this

[image: should be replaced with the text, images of code are not accessible, searchable, and they can't be copied by those trying to help you]

Comment: Put a [mre], **as text**, in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the if condition where you are checking the credentials.

You have written:

```
if emailstatus==True and email in UserKeys==True and UserKeys[email]==key:
```

here you can do two things:

1) Either remove `==True`

After alteration (1): `if emailstatus==True and email in UserKeys and UserKeys[email]==key:`

2) or place email in UserKeys in parenthesis like this: `(email in UserKeys)==True`

After alteration(2): `if emailstatus==True and (email in UserKeys)==True and UserKeys[email]==key:`

Actually if `email in UserKeys` returns `True` if that email is present so you don't have to check it explicitly

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem. Unfortunaly im new and cant  upvote you yet :c

Comment: That's fine. Glad this helped !